# How to use Azure Snapshot debugger

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-application-insights

I followed [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/profiler/profiler-bring-your-own-storage?tabs=azure-cli) to configure a BYOS and link it to app insight so I then can use snapshot debugger.

So after I linked the storage with app insight, what now? How do I actually use the snapshot debugger? I found [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/snapshot-debugger/snapshot-debugger) but I'm not sure I understand what is for example `TrackException` and I don't have an `ApplicationInsights.config` (using NLog to log to app insight).

Won't exceptions be automatically "tracked"? How do I set the debugger settings if I don't have the `ApplicationInsights.config` file? And how can I actually debug using a state that was saved when an exception was tracked?

Answer (score 0):

> Won't exceptions be automatically "tracked"?

Exceptions are tracked automatically, but when we need in depth details about the exception, we need to configure the Application Insights SDK.

> I'm not sure I understand what is for example `TrackException` and I don't have an `ApplicationInsights.config`

`TrackException` is used to track the handled and unhandled exceptions with full details.

If you want to use `NLog to log to app insights` , then `ApplicationInsights.config` is not required.

I have referred this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/snapshot-debugger/snapshot-debugger-app-service#installation) to Enable Snapshot debugger within the App Service.

We can enable the `Snapshot Debugger` within the portal itself.

In the `Azure App Service` => `Application Insights` => Under `Instrument your application`, select your framework (`.NET`).

[image]

- The settings will be added in the Configuration => Application Settings.
  [image]

***`OR`***

If you want to add more settings and If you don't have `ApplicationInsights.config`, we can create it manually and add the required settings as mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net#add-application-insights-manually).

The `ApplicationInsights.config` has to be created in the root directory of your application.

Comment: I want to add the support for the snapshot debugger for services which are hosted in an AKS cluster.. Are there maybe instructions specifically for that case in addition to what you showed for an app service? for example if i need to add something in their startup file or something like that?

Comment: Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-live-azure-kubernetes?view=vs-2022) which explains about the snapshot debug in AKS.

Comment: But I can see the option is available only in VS 2019 Enterprise Edition.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txyu9.png)

Comment: Is the link in the answer itself also a requirement in addition to the link you provided in the comment before for a service hosted in an aks cluster? Not sure if I also need to enable it or can I simply debug it straight away as the link in the comment?

Comment: Check the VS version you are using.And try to follow the link whih I ahve provided in the comment.

Comment: I'm missing something here which prevents it from working.. Could you please check out this new question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76299886/snapshot-debugging-resource-not-found-in-azure